# how to make ksql print only latest records

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am running following query on ksql. but I want ***only last 20
 records***.

```
SELECT MAX(ROWTIME),TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),SERIAL,COUNT FROM MY_STREAM WHERE TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') >= DATE AND TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') <= DATE2 GROUP BY SERIAL,COUNT LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in KSQL currently. Since KSQL is dealing with unbounded data, the 'last' records don't make so much sense, because the data is (potentially) always arriving.

Depending on what you're trying to do you could use `ROWTIME` predicate to filter data based on a time range.

Possibly you will need to use Kafka Streams instead to access the data in the pattern you're describing.

You might want to also check for existing issue to upvote here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/ and if there isn't one, create one  https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new

Comment: Is there ORDER BY clause support ? or TOPKDISTINCT

Comment: You can see all the currently supported syntax here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html

Comment: if I use count(*), it returns only 1

Comment: If I use TOPKDISTINCT(item1,5) it returns [value1,null,null,null,null]

Comment: Just adding a correction to this: `LIMIT 20` is supported by now, which displays to the *first* 20 records that would appear in the result.